# Python: Create a front-on-view of 2d Top Down floorplan

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, 3d

I am looking to map the exterior of my 2d floorplan with a facade, however, I am struggling in being able to create a front on view of my 2d top-down floorplan.

I have tried using `opencv` to segment the needed areas, and while I can easily identify the doors and windows, I cannot seem to find a way to segment the front-on view.

[image: The left is a floorplan which I want to map, and the right is end goal - it is the highlighted view of the floorplan with the door and window coloured]

The left is a floorplan which I want to map, and the right is end goal - it is the highlighted view of the floorplan with the door and window coloured.

Thank you in advance.

---

## Edited

Updating question with some code in line with the suggestion in the comment.
I have iterates vertically from top to bottom and identified the last pixel (right side) in each row which is black or yellow. I then reverse these to get the list from left (bottom) to right (top) and then iterate over that to build a 2d array with their respective heights (255 pixels for a wall) and (204 pixels for a door).

However, I am not getting the right result

The code is below:

```js
from PIL import Image
import inspect

floorplan_path = 'data/floorplan.png'

class Wall(object):

  colorIdentifier = (79,79,79)

  def __init__(self, x,y):
    self.position = (x,y)
    self.color = (79,79,79)
    self.height = 255
    self.drawColor = (65,105,225)

class Door(object):

  colorIdentifier = (255,255,25)

  def __init__(self, x,y):
    self.position = (x,y)
    self.color = (255,255,25)
    self.height = 204
    self.drawColor = (255, 255, 25)

# Not implemented yet
class Window:
  position = None
  color = None # Not Sure how to identify this yet
  drawColor = None # Light Blue
  height = 204

def main():
  image = Image.open(floorplan_path)
  pixels = list(image.getdata())
  image = image.convert('RGB')
  width, height = image.size

  rowItems = []

  for y in range(0, height):

    blacks = []

    for x in range(0, width):
      pixel = image.getpixel((x,y))
      color = pixel

      if(color == Wall.colorIdentifier):
        blacks.append(Wall(x, y))
      elif (color == Door.colorIdentifier):
        blacks.append(Door(x, y))
    # Add last item in row as the wall we want the front view for is the right side
    if blacks != []:
      rowItems.append(blacks[-1])
  
  # Remove rows with no values
  y = [x for x in rowItems if x != []] 

  # Making the wall start from left to right (bottom to top)
  leftToRight = list(reversed(y))

  # A 2d array containing the rows and column of the images with their respected color and height (len of array)
  imageArray = []

  for item in leftToRight:

    if isinstance(item, Wall):
      column = [item.drawColor] * item.height
      imageArray.append(column)
    elif isinstance(item, Door):
      column = [item.drawColor] * item.height
      column.append(Wall.drawColor) * (255-item.height)
      imageArray.append(column)  

  img = Image.new('RGB', (255, 255))

  for i in range(len(imageArray)):
    for j in range(len(imageArray[i])):
      img.putpixel((i, j), (imageArray[i][j]))

  img.save('output.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and the output using the floorplan on the left above is
[image]

Comment: do it manually? there's no reason to write any code if you need this once

Comment: no, need it dynamically for any floorplan in a similar style to the one on the left

Comment: what are distinguishing attributes of a wall, door, window, as seen in the floor plan?

Comment: exterior walls are always black, doors are always yellow and windows look like that all the time

Comment: while interior walls are the light grey

Comment: Go from right to left (or any other defibed direction), row by row and for the first non-white pixel you "hit" create a front-view column of the "class" of the hit pixel. E.g. if you hit a wall pixel, write a blue column,if you hit a door pixel, write a 80% yellow and 20% blue column, and so on...

Comment: You need a 3D model, not a just a floorpan to convert to a face-on view, unless you know the height that you need for the walls and doors. But then you might as well do it manually